# Xamarin Forms - getting the file name of an image held in local storage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to get the file name of an image source where that source is `ImageSource.FromStream`?

If I have 2 images in XAML, image01 and image02. The source for image01 is myImage and is included in the app bundle so I can get the name easily using `string _source = image01.Source.ToString()`.

If I want the file name for image02 which resides in local storage as myImage2 how would I do that?  `image02.Source.ToString()` returns `File: n.Forms.StreamImageSource`

Comment: I'd say depends on the image format. Not sure therefore this is not an answer, but many formats embed metadata (EXIF) and if the (*original*) filename was stored in one of the EXIF properties, you could retrieve it from the stream data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [paraphrased] Can I get the file name from `ImageSource.FromStream`?

No. A `Stream` is an object which holds a load of bytes in memory. It doesn't store the location of where those bytes came from. The data inside a `Stream` could have come from a file, a web page, or any other source.

If you want to point to an image in your local storage, you will need to hard-code the folder location. Then you can search by filename extension. For example:

```cs
private const string MyStorageLocation = "/0/external/Pictures"; // Or wherever

private string[] GetAllPngImages()
{
    return System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(MyStorageLocation, "*.png", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}
```

The `string[]` will contain a list of available images. You would then assign the source of `image02` to one of those images using `ImageSource.FromFile`:

```cs
image02.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(images[0]);
```